# Boundary of fibers of submersions

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, differential-topology

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with boundary (say of dimension $m$) and let $N$ be a smooth manifold with no boundary (say of dimension $n$ with $m\geq n$). We have the following classical result:

**Theorem**: Let $f:M\rightarrow N$ be a **surjective** smooth map. Let $x\in N$ be a **regular value** of both, $f$ and $f|_{\partial M}$. Then $f^{-1}(x)$ is a manifold with boundary of dimension $m-n$ ( note that $f^{-1}(x)$ is never empty since $f$ is surjective). Furthermore $\partial (f^{-1}(x))=f^{-1}(x)\cap\partial M$.

So I'm especially interested by the last part of the theorem. So if we remove the assumption
that $x$ is a regular value of $f|_{\partial M}$ then there is no reason for the theorem to hold true.

Q1: What are interesting families of manifolds (over a fixed $N$ that we always assumed to be without boundary) for which $\partial (f^{-1}(x))\neq (f^{-1}(x)\cap\partial M)$?

Q2: In general do we have some set relationship between $\partial (f^{-1}(x))$ and $(f^{-1}(x)\cap\partial M)$?

Comment: Take a compact disc, and any real-valued function on it with no critical points.  That's a pretty typical example.

Comment: if you remove the hypothesis that f is regular on the boudary, then $X=f^{-1}(x)\cap M$ is a, not necessarily proper, sub-manifold of the interior of $M$. In general $\partial X$ may empty, defined, or even not being well-defined in the sense of manifolds. If $X$ accumulates to the boundary, the accomulation points belong to $f^{-1}(x)\cap\partial M$, but can be smaller than that (example: take a cylynder, collapse the boundary components to points to get a spehre and map it to R)

Comment: So I thought about the example about the solid cylinder in $R^3$ (of length $1$) along the $x$-axis and center at $(0,0,0)$ where $f$ is the distance between the projection of a point $P$ on $x$ and $(0,0,0)$. But I found this example a bit artificial since in this case, $N$ is really just $[-1/2,1/2]$ since the fibers outside this interval are empty. But now I just realize that one may identify the two end points of that interval to get a circle. Ok, I see so anything can happen. I guess this answers my question.